# PayPal default IPN address

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

in my website, usually I use a specific IPN handler (which is stored in the preferences of my PayPal profile) in order to process transactions.

Currently, I'm developing a new feature and I would like to handle the transactions related to this feature through a different IPN handler.

Is it sufficient to add to the post request a variable called notify_url? Or should I do something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The IPN handler specified from within your account can be programmatically overridden. The implementation depends on what platform you are using.

[Dynamically Setting the Notification URL](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup#id091GJ202030) :

**Using a Website Payments Standard button**
Modify the `notify_url` HTML form variable

**Using an NVP API operation**
Set the `NOTIFYURL` field of the DoDirectPayment, DoExpressCheckoutPayment, or DoReferenceTransaction request

**Using an SOAP API operation**
Set the `NotifyURL` field of the DoDirectPayment, DoExpressCheckoutPayment, or DoReferenceTransaction request

**Using the Adaptive Payments API operation**
Set the `ipnNotificationUrl` field of the Pay or Preapproval request